# Performance issue when hosting a WPF form in a native C++ application

Tags: c++, wpf, performance, native

I have WPF window which runs fine when hosted in a WPF application but when I load it from within my native C++ application it takes a very long time to render and the UI Thread blocks until it completes.

The main offender on my window is an series of items controls used to display a 9 by 12 grid of icons which represent states of components within my system.

The whole items control takes up to 14 seconds for its initial render. (This is almost instant when running in a WPF app)

Each line has a text header that when clicked displays a small summary of data (max, min, mean, std dev) for each of the status icons. clicking this header can take up to 4 seconds to render the summary but is instant in my WPF app.

Are there any known tricks for making WPF perform nicely within a native application?

[Edit]

I have just tried launching it from a large .NET windows forms application using the following code:

```
    public bool? ShowWpfDialog(System.Windows.Window window, Form owner)
    {
        var helper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window)
                         {Owner = (owner == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : owner.Handle};
        return window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I have the same performance issues as when running from the native app. (the .net app also runs native code.)

[Edit]

When I don't use the WindowInteropHelper the code performs properly:

```
    public bool? ShowWpfDialog(System.Windows.Window window, Form owner)
    {
        //var helper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window)
        //                 {Owner = (owner == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : owner.Handle};
        return window.ShowDialog();
    }
```

What is the WindowInteropHelper  doing that would cause a performance issue?

[Edit]

Could there be an issue with the way resources are resolved when I load it with an owner using the WindowInteropHelper?

Comment: Are you running/timing in the debugger?

Comment: The times are based on an observation when running a release build

Comment: Are you still running in the VS hosting process, or standalone/outside VS?

Comment: Is loading that window the very first thing that happens in your native app that makes use of .NET and/or WPF?

Comment: I have run it in a release build outside of VS.

Comment: It is loaded from a menu in a large existing native application.

Comment: Is that C++/CLR? I would point in the direction of the interop / threading comfiguration. Threading model could be the problem. Have you tried a profiler debug in visual studio to see where thigns are hanging? 14 seconds is an awful lot of time - that should show up visibly.

Comment: +1 for profiling it. I looked around a bit and some people seem to have performance issues related to automation hooks in WPF. Maybe this is related - a profile should tell us more.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: You mean this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110 ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: A lot of performance problems can be related to Windows theming, visual styles, and the version of Windows you're running on. Native applications can start with different parameters than builtin .NET/WPF ones. I suggest these readings to get ideas: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2-performance-tuning.aspx and ultimately use the WPF performance suite tooling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa969767(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Even I came across this issue where in WPF application takes time to render, but not within a C++ application. I still have not solved the issue but I read about caching resources somewhere in order to speed up the startup. Im not sure if this would lead you to the right direction or not

Comment: Why are you using WindowInteropHelper anyway? Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for WindowInteropHelper indicate that you should set the HELPER'S handle to your c++ handle

```
WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(myDialog);
wih.Owner = ownerHwnd;
myDialog.ShowDialog();
```

But you seem to be doing the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your post do you mention [HwndSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost(v=vs.110).aspx) which are the supported means of interoping between native code (either hosting WPF in Win32 or visa versa).  `WindowsInteropHelper` is not intended to support full blown interop scenarios, it's only use is to basically get the Handle of a WPF `Window`.

[These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829(v=vs.110).aspx) are a great series of articles and I recommend looking through them, because what you want to do is not going to be trivial unless it's a very limited scope.

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating and using native images of your .NET-assembly via [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), this will significantly speed things up although i dont know how big the difference will be in your case ... at least it should reduce loading times

Comment: I will try this if I can't find another solution - I don't know if I will be allowed to do this in our integrated build environment

Comment: No. 14 seconds is nuts, plus he says it works fast in a wpf application and that is 99% not ngened - pointing in the wrong direction. Even startingg runtime should not be 14 seconds.

Comment: The starting run time is not 14 seconds - the window opens quickly and then the control - which responds to data it gets from a service- takes up to 14 seconds to render. It seams to only do this when the window has an owner attached using the WindowInteropHelper,

If I simplify my templates they render a lot faster which makes me believe it could be something to do with the resource resolution in the larger application.

Comment: actually claiming that .NET is "not ngened" (whatever that means) just proves a major lack of knowledge. .NET-applications are _always_ "ngened", thats the MAIN REASON for using .NET - compiled bytecode will be translated into native code at runtime, this is done in-memory ("ngened") and immediately before the resulting code is being used. NGEN is just a tool speed this process up, it pre-compiles everything.
Maybe stop assuming things .... just a suggestion

Comment: Please stop using "ngen" to mean JIT compilation, which indeed is always done. Ngen specifically refers to running the compilation ahead of time and storing the resulting native code on disk. Saying .NET always ngens is completely incorrect.

Comment: completely bullshit - .NET assemblies are translated into native code EVERY TIME YOU START THE APPLICATION, this is necessary due to native pointers being somewhat dynamic. Once again : stop assuming things. Although : one may very well produce native code as a result of .NET - calls which are actually cached images, but this is rarely the case - only the CLR itself is able to decide about whether to use cached images or create new ones.